# Central Admin CSS is messed up after upgrade to SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, wss-3.0, upgrade

I have just finished upgrading to  SharePoint 2010 but my central admin doesnt have any pictures. It looks like the CSS is messed up.

Any ideas?

Many thanks

Comment: Did you try to use ctrl+f5 to reload the cache, it might be a local problem.

Comment: I tried that and it is messed up.

Comment: Have you removed central admin and then rerun the setup wizard to put it all back?

Comment: I have passed through that stage. It looks like its not rendering the css and if thats' possible.

Comment: Is the css linked in the page source? Can you browse to the linked location? Does viewing in Firebug or Chrome dev tools give insights as to what isn't being viewed? Is it all images + javascript or just images or all of the styling too?

Comment: Everything (Images, Styling, and Javascript).

Comment: Are they in the page source? Can you go to the file manually? What is the issue when you try to get the file manually, is it 401,403,404,500 etc? Need to dig a little deeper if you have tried the standard stuff.

Comment: If I use firebug and select the images not rendered. Still it doesn't display the selected image. No error, just a blank page.

Comment: What about the CSS and JavaScript can you manually get to those files following the urls in the source? Check your server logs for file requests also.

Comment: it returns the following error message:
Failed to load resource: The server responded with a status 401 (Unauthorized)

Comment: There are dozens of reasons for this, check your server logs and windows logs, and uls to locate more information, then head back to google, I would say perhaps you have to reset folder permissions or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to change the theme?

Comment: What do you mean change the theme Seb.

Comment: Everything uses the default themes'

Comment: And with another theme? do you still have any problems?